# Convert Simple C# Console>Service to perform repeated API calls and file system actions

Tags: c#, beginner, .net

I was sent here from StackOverflow, as it was indicated that the quality of my current approach may have been questionable. I'm attempting to transform a simple console application so that it may be used as a service using a nested `Service` class (relevant code below). The intent is to create a service to perform the actions within the `Run` method more-or-less at a regular interval. I'm new to .NET, so please bare with me if there are obvious flaws in my implementation.

In short, the Service's `OnStart` calls my own `Start` method once, which creates a timer. Inside the timer, I'm creating an instance of the `Program` class, and performing the `Run` method till it finishes. I believe this is a valid implementation of what I want that doesn't leave resources outstanding, although I am unsure whether I should dispose of the `Prg` object at the end of CallTimer. Part of what the `Run` method does is build a dictionary of actions on the file system that were unsuccessful so that they may be attempted again in the next run.

I'm a bit green and not terribly confident that I'm doing things correctly, but I'm attempting to get up to speed as quickly as possible, so any assistance is appreciated. I can provide additional details if needed.

```
partial class Program{
    static object timerLck = new object();

    public class Service : ServiceBase{
        public Service(){
            ServiceName = Program.ServiceName;
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args){
            Program.Start(args);
        }
        protected override void OnStop(){
            Program.Stop();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args){
        if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
            using (var service = new Service())
                ServiceBase.Run(service);
        else{
            Start(args);
            Stop();
        }
    }

    private static void Start(string[] args){
        Timer t = new Timer(CallTimer, null, 0, 50000);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Stop(){
        //log service stopped
    }

    static void CallTimer(object state){
        bool Lock = false;
        Dictionary<string, Metadata> PreviousErrors = new Dictionary<string, Metadata>();
        try{
            Lock = Monitor.TryEnter(timerLck);
            if (Lock){
                Program Prg = new Program()
                var task = Task.Run(()=>Prg.Run(PreviousErrors));
                PreviousErrors = task.Result;
            }
        }
        finally{
            if (Lock) Monitor.Exit(timerLck);
        }
    }

    //Perform the repeated actions here 
    private async Task<Dictionary<string, Metadata>> Run(Dictionary<string, Metadata> previousErrors){
        Dictionary<string, Metadata> d = new Dictionary<string, Metadata>();
        //...            
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: This `//???` and that `//...`  is off-topic on Code Review. You need to put something in there, this is, post the complete code ;-)

Comment: t3chb0t, Thank you for responding and for the edit. I'm not currently doing anything in `Stop` other than logging that the service stopped (I have now clarified the comment). I left the contents off of `Run` because it would increase the code substantially and I was really hoping to get clarification on the overall structure of the Service rather than the details of `Run`, which changed minimally. Is this inappropriate?

Comment: Where is `ServiceBase` coming from (I'm guessing `System.ServiceProcess`, but why do I need to guess -- you should include the relevant `using`s)? There is no `ServiceName` in `Program`, so where is that coming from? What is `Metadata`? `Program Prg = new Program()` is lacking a `;` at the end. Putting `{` at the end of the line instead of on a line of their own is not a standard C# coding style.

Comment: The character limit for a question on Code Review is over 65k characters. You won't even come close. Please provide the full code, including usings and imports of types.

Comment: Please move the Service class and the timer code to a seperate file.
Also place the opening brackets on a new line. file. It is cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: _Run_ is stub code. Please provide sufficient context for us to review your code. Visit our help center to verify how to ask a question that is on-topic for this site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.